# Copy text to clipboard upon keypress

Tags: jquery, clipboard.js

It is possible to use this library to bind *copy to clipboard* to a keyboard short-cut?

All the [usage examples](https://clipboardjs.com/#usage) assume there's a button on the page and wait until the user presses that button. But I need to trigger it with the keyboard.

My attempts don't even trigger any callback. I've there's a trigger I need to issue manually, I can't find it:

```js
jQuery(function($){
  var $placeholder = $("div:first");
  var clipboard = new ClipboardJS($placeholder[0]);
  
  $("textarea").on("keyup", function(event){
    var text;

    if (event.key === "s") {
      text = "Test / " + Math.round(1000000 * Math.random());
      console.log("Copying '%s' to clipboard...", text);
      $placeholder.attr("data-clipboard-text", text);

      clipboard.on('success', function(e) {
        console.info('Action:', e.action);
        console.info('Text:', e.text);
        console.info('Trigger:', e.trigger);
        e.clearSelection();
      });
      clipboard.on('error', function(e) {
        console.error('Action:', e.action);
        console.error('Trigger:', e.trigger);
      });
      // And now what?
    }
  })
});
```

```css
textarea{
  width: 100%;
  color: red;
}
textarea:focus{
  color: green;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/clipboard@2/dist/clipboard.min.js"></script>
<textarea>Type "s" here to save some text to clipboard. Then use Ctrl+V to see if it worked.</textarea>
<div></div>
```

Comment: You'd basically haft to bind a keydown/keyup on body and listen to it with jQuery.
Try body instead of textarea.

Comment: My actual code has `$(document).on("keyup")` instead of `$("textarea").on("keyup")`. Switching to `"body"` doesn't seem to change anything. The problem is that I don't know how to tell `ClipboardJS` to trigger copy on keyboard event since it's clearly expecting a click.

Comment: Probably need to focus the body as well, since it's not in focus after entering.

Comment: Sorry if I'm not explaining myself properly. Just look at the runnable snippet in the question. I only have `new ClipboardJS($placeholder[0])` because the constructor requires an element but `$placeholder[0]` is completely irrelevant here. Can I just tell him: "user wants data, please do your stuff now"?

Comment: just stating body worked fine for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think I found the point I was missing. I basically need to trigger the click event myself. I've replaced my `<div>` place-holder with something more obvious:

```js
jQuery(function($){
  var $dummyButton = $("button:first");
  var clipboard = new ClipboardJS($dummyButton[0]);
  clipboard.on('success', function(e) {
    console.info('Action:', e.action);
    console.info('Text:', e.text);
    console.info('Trigger:', e.trigger);
    e.clearSelection();
  });
  clipboard.on('error', function(e) {
    console.error('Action:', e.action);
    console.error('Trigger:', e.trigger);
  });

  $("textarea").on("keyup", function(event){
    var text;

    if (event.key === "s") {
      text = "Test / " + Math.round(1000000 * Math.random());
      console.log("Copying '%s' to clipboard...", text);
      $dummyButton.attr("data-clipboard-text", text);

      $dummyButton.trigger("click");
    }
  })
});
```

```css
textarea{
  width: 100%;
  color: red;
}
textarea:focus{
  color: green;
}
button {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/clipboard@2/dist/clipboard.min.js"></script>
<textarea>Type "s" here to save some text to clipboard. Then use Ctrl+V to see if it worked.</textarea>
<button>Dummy button</button>
```

This works in desktop browsers like Firefox, Chrome, Edge, IE11 (this browser asks the user for permission) and possibly many others.

Comment: Thanks for this, I did a not of head-scratching before finding this solution which works for vanilla Javascript as well by just including it in an IIFE and rejiggering the nomenclature accordingly. There is nothing on the ClipboardJS website that indicates that keyboard events are supported, but also nothing that says they aren't.

Answer (score 0):

Solution without jQuery:

```js
/** Copies a string directly to the clipboard with a simulated button click. */
const copy = s => {
  const dummyButton = document.createElement('button')
  const clipboard = new ClipboardJS(dummyButton, { text: () => s })
  dummyButton.click()
}

// copy on keydown
window.addEventListener('keydown', e => {
  if (e.key === 's') {
    copy('Hello universe')
  }
})
```

The browser focus will move to the dummy button element, so you may need to restore the focus afterwards with `el.focus()`.